# Why are lambda-abstractions the only terms that are values in the untyped lambda calculus?

Tags: logic, lambda-calculus

I am confused about the following claim: "The only values in the untyped lambda calculus are lambda-abstractions".

Why are the other terms not values? What does it mean for a lambda-abstraction to be a value? The first thing that came to my mind was that maybe lambda-abstractions are the only possible normal forms, but this is not true of course, e.g. $(\lambda x.\; x)\;y \to y$.

Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: Where did you see that? The definition of value may vary.

Comment: $(\lambda x. x)\ y$ is not a lambda abstraction, it's an application, namely, the application of $(\lambda x. x)$ to $y$.

Comment: @DaveClarke: I think Jeroen meant that $y$ was a normal form (to disprove that a value is an abstraction) and not that $(λx.x)y$ was an abstraction (to disprove that an abstraction is a value).

Comment: I see. It wasn't clear. Perhaps a citation is in order, @Jeroen, so that we can interpret it from context. Generally, we are interested in closed expressions, which would rule out your example. In addition, we do not evaluate within lambda abstractions (in both call-by-value and call-by-name strategies), so a lambda abstraction is a normal form. For closed terms in the pure lambda calculus, they are the only normal forms.

Comment: Variables are always values, in every calculi.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. @DaveClarke: The question comes from someone else, but I know that he uses B.Pierce's book. I myself do not have it with me ATM so I can't check but I believe that the chapter on the untyped lambda-calculus is one of the first ones (CH5 if I can recall correctly). It should be stated in there.

Comment: @DaveClarke: I just checked Pierce's book. The confusion arised because the lambda-calculus' operational semantics is first touched on informally. It is there said in a footnote that the only values of the calculus are lambda-abstractions. Later, when the semantics is formally defined, it becomes clear that only closed terms are being considered.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a number of things going on here:

- The language you are talking about has no additional data types, otherwise there would be other kinds of values.
- The reduction strategy of the language does not reduce inside lambda abstractions. Both call-by-value and call-by-name conform to this. Otherwise, not every lambda abstraction would be a normal.
- One generally considers closed expressions as programs, so there are no free variables, hence the example you present is not considered.

Other terms are not values because they can be reduced or they do not appear in closed programs.

That a lambda abstraction is a value means that it cannot be reduced any further (depending on the reduction strategy).

For open terms, variables are also values.

Comment: This makes sense. The main thing I get out of it is that only closed terms should be taken into consideration. I will check with the original source to see if that is part of the formal definition of the operational semantics.